# Angular 12 / Typescript issue with type never

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

I am using Angular 12 and this code below is complaining.

```
this.recorder.ondataavailable = (event: { data: any; }) => {
  this.recordedChunks.push(event.data);
};
```

Typescript is giving me this error:

```
Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)
(parameter) event: {
    data: any;
}
```

Comment: That normally indicates a `never[]` array, but we can't see how it's defined.

Comment: How do you define recorder and recordedChunks?

Comment: public recorder: any;  
  public recordedChunks = [];

Comment: Without more information, the type of `[]` is indeed inferred as `never[]`. Be explicit about what you intend to put in the array.

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is define your result as a string array, like the following:

data : any[];

Comment: That didn't work